# Round all index to 30 min in Pandas datetimeindex

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetimeindex, pandas-timeindex

I know about round, ceil, floor functions.

```
df.index.round("30min")
```

This rounds to the nearest 30 minute interval. What I want is that each is rounded to 30 minutes.

In the case of .round 10:15 will be rounded to 10:30 and 10:45 to 11:00. I would want both rounded to 10:30.

The datetime Index:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2021-11-29 09:30:00', '2021-11-29 09:45:00',
               '2021-11-29 10:00:00', '2021-11-29 10:15:00',
               '2021-11-29 10:30:00', '2021-11-29 10:45:00',
               '2021-11-29 11:00:00', '2021-11-29 11:15:00',
               '2021-11-29 11:30:00', '2021-11-29 11:45:00',
               ...
               '2021-12-27 13:30:00', '2021-12-27 13:45:00',
               '2021-12-27 14:00:00', '2021-12-27 14:15:00',
               '2021-12-27 14:30:00', '2021-12-27 14:45:00',
               '2021-12-27 15:00:00', '2021-12-27 15:15:00',
               '2021-12-27 15:30:00', '2021-12-27 15:45:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Datetime', length=520, freq=None)
```

Comment: What to do with 11:00?

Comment: change to 11:30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DatetimeIndex.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor.html) by hour and add 30 minutes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.DatetimeIndex(
               ['2021-11-29 09:30:00', '2021-11-29 09:45:00',
               '2021-11-29 10:00:00', '2021-11-29 10:15:00',
               '2021-11-29 10:30:00', '2021-11-29 10:45:00',
               '2021-11-29 11:00:00', '2021-11-29 11:15:00',
               '2021-11-29 11:30:00', '2021-11-29 11:45:00',
               '2021-12-27 13:30:00', '2021-12-27 13:45:00',
               '2021-12-27 14:00:00', '2021-12-27 14:15:00',
               '2021-12-27 14:30:00', '2021-12-27 14:45:00',
               '2021-12-27 15:00:00', '2021-12-27 15:15:00',
               '2021-12-27 15:30:00', '2021-12-27 15:45:00']))

print (df.index.floor("1H") + pd.Timedelta('30min'))

DatetimeIndex(['2021-11-29 09:30:00', '2021-11-29 09:30:00',
               '2021-11-29 10:30:00', '2021-11-29 10:30:00',
               '2021-11-29 10:30:00', '2021-11-29 10:30:00',
               '2021-11-29 11:30:00', '2021-11-29 11:30:00',
               '2021-11-29 11:30:00', '2021-11-29 11:30:00',
               '2021-12-27 13:30:00', '2021-12-27 13:30:00',
               '2021-12-27 14:30:00', '2021-12-27 14:30:00',
               '2021-12-27 14:30:00', '2021-12-27 14:30:00',
               '2021-12-27 15:30:00', '2021-12-27 15:30:00',
               '2021-12-27 15:30:00', '2021-12-27 15:30:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```